# How do you monitor the performance of a character device (e.g. tape drive)?

Tags: performance-monitoring, tape, io, tapedrive

There are many ways to monitor block device performance:  dstat and iostat, heck, even sar will give you data on block device I/O rates.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any good spur-of-the-moment tools for monitoring the performance of a character device like a tape drive.

I know there are tools to monitor performance if you remember in advance to do it (pv, dd + SIGUSR1, probably others), but say you're 2 hours into a job that might be 3 hours or 30 hours depending on the performance, and you don't know which it is.

The only thing I can think of is some elaborate use of strace or similar, parsing the output for bytes written, maybe with timestamps.  Is there a commonly used tool that I've forgotten or never heard of?

Comment: Have you checked if the device offers ay stats via SNMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [SystemTAP](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/HomePage) script for SCSI tape devices:

http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/WSiostatSCSI

I haven't tried it; don't know what kind of shape it's in.

Comment: This looks very nice; I've been wanting to learn more about SystemTAP.

Comment: Just listing the name of another unteseted tool is not a very useful answer. We all have search engines.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, HP has a program which can check HP tape device's performance. You can find it on [here](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storageworks/ltt/index.html)

I guess other tape device vendors also have similar tools for monitoring tape device's real time status. You can check their website for this kind of applications. Good luck.